# Activate Gmail vacation reply from Thunderbird

Tags: gmail, thunderbird

Is there a trick to activate Gmail vacation auto-reply service from Thunderbird, without having to log into Gmail account via web browser?

It's too many steps for such a simple and yet important feature.

Comment: How about this -> http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=2362453

Comment: @sgtbeano Hm this is for Thunderbird in-app auto-reply feature. I need to activate Gmail auto-reply feature via Thunderbird